# OAuth authentication with PKCE

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, oauth, .net-core

I'm trying to implement [OAuth authentication with PKCE](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/auth-overview/#authorization-code-with-pkce-flow) in .NET Core.

Following [this tutorial](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/) I was able to implement the pure OAuth part.
Then, checking on how PKCE works I have seen tutorials like [this one](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/ASPNET-Core-using-Proof-Key-for-Code-Exchange-PKCE) that shows how to implement it using `OpenID`.

If we check the tutorial there are two main steps needed for PKCE:

1. Add `code_challenge` to the authorization request.
2. Add `code_verifier` to the token request.

The first one I can make just fine, as you can see on the commented code below.
Problem comes when I need to add the `code_verifier` to the Token request.
As far as I understood, .Net Core middleware already takes care of getting the authorization code and request for token automatically, without asking me, and I couldn't find a place to intercept the token request and put the `code_verifier` on it. So basically what I get back is an error from my OAuth Provider telling that the request contains no `code_verifier`.

Here is my code:

```
.AddOAuth("MyOAuth", options =>
{
    options.ClientId = securityConfig.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = securityConfig.ClientSecret;
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/oauthCallback");

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = securityConfig.AuthorizationEndpoint;
    options.TokenEndpoint = securityConfig.TokenEndpoint;
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = securityConfig.UserInfoEndpoint;

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var jUser = JObject.Parse(user);

            context.RunClaimActions(jUser);

        },
        OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
        {

            //var codeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(32);

            //context.Properties.Items.Add("codeVerifier", codeVerifier);

            //string codeChallenge;
            //using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            //{
            //    var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
            //    codeChallenge = Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
            //}

            //context.RedirectUri += $"&code_challenge={codeChallenge}&code_challenge_method=S256";

            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTicketReceived = context => Task.CompletedTask
    };
});
```

Any ideas on how I should pass the `code_verifier` in the token request?

Thanks in advance